# Inno Setup : How to set installer "Run As Administrator"?

Tags: inno-setup

In Inno Setup,

```
[Setup] 
PrivilegesRequired=admin
```

is still can not Run the installer as Administrator, but I need to Launch my Program at last step of Inno Setup.

How can I do to set my Installer can Run as Administrator ?

Comment: which version of OS you were trying this on? whats the error you are getting ?

Comment: Do you want to run the setup as administrator or to run another program with administrator privileges from the installer?

Comment: As long as you do NOT explicitly choose the menu option "Run as Administrator" then Inno will do all the correct things by default -- the install itself will run as admin and your application at the end will run as NOT admin.

Comment: @Miral: Do you mean the installed program will run as admin if installed by simply double clicking on installer? If yes, then I partially agree with you (`runascurrentuser` flag may be required in `RUN` section), but if you mean otherwise, I do not agree with you.

Comment: No.  I'm saying that if the Inno installer is *not* run as administrator directly, then even if `PrivilegesRequired=admin`, running the application at the end as a `postinstall` action defaults to running it as the pre-admin user (`runasoriginaluser`).  However this fails and the application is run as the admin user if the user uses Run As Administrator explicitly when running the installer (since in that case the original user and current user are the same).

Answer (score 48):

I have been having this same problem as well, it took me quite a bit of time to figure out that after you have set the `PrivilegesRequired=admin` you also need to add `runascurrentuser` to all the `Flags` under `[Run]` section.

```
[Setup]
PrivilegesRequired=admin

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,MyApp}"; Flags: runascurrentuser nowait postinstall skipifsilent; Check: returnTrue()
Filename: "{app}\MyApp.exe"; Flags: runascurrentuser; Parameters: "-install -svcName ""MyApp"" -svcDesc ""MyApp"" -mainExe ""MyApp.exe""  "; Check: returnFalse()
```

I know you have probably already figured out the issue considering this question was asked over two years ago but I thought I would answer it anyway for others like myself who found this unanswered question but would have really liked to have seen an answer.

Comment: FWIW, specifying `runascurrentuser` will try to run the application with admin permissions.  This should almost never be what you actually want, since applications that require admin permissions are usually bad.  (Most of the time it indicates that you're doing something wrong in the application code.)  Also, it's not necessary to specify this flag on non-`postinstall` entries (where it's more acceptable), as it's the default.  And the reason this question didn't have an answer is that the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Miral Please tell us why it does not make sense, thank you.

Comment: The English in the question is poor and it's unclear what the actual problem was.  It seems to say "if I set PrivilegesRequired=admin then the installer does not run as admin", which is entirely incorrect.  And I already explained above why the application should not be run as admin.

Comment: @Miral sometimes you have to run some batch script post-installation as admin. Thats why I found this question. Why so salty?

Comment: @moTHO. This question is not relevant to your question.  For your question you just use `[Run]` without `postinstall` and without any theatrics.  Or better yet, use `[Code]` instead of a batch file, since you have more control over things that way.  And I'm not being salty, I am stating facts.

Answer (score 1):

My inno setup script is belowing,

```
#define MyAppName "MyApp"  
#define MyAppExeName "MyApp.exe"

[Setup]  
PrivilegesRequired=admin

[Run]   
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: runascurrentuser nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Comment: What does that do?

Comment: @Matthieu, it is script for inno setup compiler. I use this codes to run my app as administrator at the end of installation.

Comment: You might want to edit your answer with a bit more information then. As it is, it's just code and we don't know what to do with it (especially for those just starting with Inno Setup).